# calling function after input in haskell

Tags: list, function, haskell, input

It is a part of a homework.
I need to write a function that reads info from the input until empty line. After that function puts first, third, fifth ... line symbols as one String and second, fourth ... as another String.
Signature is `combine :: IO (String , String)`

I have written a function that takes a list as argument and puts 1,3,5.. to one `String` a 2,4,6 symbols to another `String`. Function is here:

```
intotwo (x : xs)
   = let
      (us , vs)
         = intotwo xs
   in
   (x : vs , us)
intotwo _
   = ([] , [])
```

Also I have written a code that reads an input: It is here:

```
combine
   = do
      lines <- getLine
      if null lines
         then return ([], [])
         else do
            linesagain <- combine
            return --what should I return?
```

Can anybody help me to finish my homework (optional: give some tips)?

Comment: You haven't explained where you are stuck now. What is your train of thought, what is missing to achieve a working result?

Comment: return statement in else branch. I mean how I need to call a fucntion to achieve the required result.

Comment: The expression that is "returned" (note that return is not the same as a return in C) must match the type expected in the signature of the function. So, `return` must lift something into the IO monad, which means you have to return a tuple of strings.

Comment: I know that I should return a tuple of String, but I do know know how finish my task.

Comment: Well, you might want to rethink your approach. One other approach could be to read in all lines into one list first, and then partition that list using combine into two lists, which you return using `return`.

Comment: envu, can you show how to return one list?

Comment: I'll only explain it so that you can fiddle around. Just think of a recursive function that reads in lines and accumulates them in a list, until it receives an empty line (just what your combine function currently does). When an empty line is read, return the accumulated list of strings. The signature could be similar to `read :: [[Char]] -> IO([[Char]])`. You might want to avoid returning something in the IO monad, but it works either way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll give a few hints to help you solve your problem.

Firstly, it is a HUGE help to give types to all the functions you define. This lets the compiler tell you immediately if a function isn't doing what you think it is doing. It also helps you when you need to join different parts of your program together.

Secondly, it is a very good idea to only solve one problem per function. Your intotwo function follows this well, it does its job of splitting a list very well. Your combine function however looks like it is trying to do too much, which will make it harder to write. I would split that function into two smaller functions.

Finally, there is a very useful special function called `undefined`. This matches any type, and helps you write a function. The trick is to start with the whole function equalling undefined (and compiling but crashing when run), and progressively improve the function until it does what you want and has no more undefines in it.

So firstly, I would add a type signature to the intotwo function. THe type is `[a] -> ([a], [a])`.

Next, I would write a function that reads lines from input until it hits an empty line, then returns the list of lines read. This function would have the type:

```
readLinesUntilEmpty :: IO [String]
readLinesUntilEmpty = undefined
```

An implementation that nearly does this is this:

```
readLinesUntilEmpty = do
  nextLine <- getLine
  rest <- readLinesUntilEmpty
  return (nextLine : rest)
```

However this never stops reading (note how nextLine isn't checked for being empty).

the following function shows how you can do this (but I'm leaving some of the implementation out):

```
readLinesUntilEmpty = do
  nextLine <- getLine
  case nextLine of
    "" -> do
      undefined -- TODO fix me
    _ -> do
      undefined -- TODO fix me
```

You should be able to figure out the rest from there.

Next, your intotwo function returns two lists of strings, but you are expected to join them together again. Eg `["this", "that"]` should turn into `"this\nthat"`. The type of such a function is `[String] -> String`:

```
joinLines :: [String] -> String
joinLines = undefined -- TODO
```

This is an easier function to write than the inttotwo func, so you should be fine.

Finally, you can link those three functions together to get your result:

```
combine :: IO (String, String)
combine = do
  lines <- readLinesUntilEmpty
  let (oddLines, evenLines) = intotwo lines
  return $ (joinLines oddLines, joinLines evenLines)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you need multiple strings reading, you need a recursive input. Or you can just use getContents, but i'm not sure whether it's good for interactive I/O. 
Something like this:

```
combine = getContents
          >>= return . intotwo
```